# Get an O(N) algorithm to find a product of a collection of numbers with a strange constraint

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

This is a question when I participated a recent interview, I think it interesting. Let's say int n=10;

Input : An array   `int a[10];`

Output: An array `float b[10];`

Requirement:

```
b[0]= a[1]*a[2]*...a[9];  //  product of all numbers in a, other than a[0]; 
b[1]= a[0]*a[2]*...a[9];  //  product of all numbers in a, other than a[1];
....
b[9]= a[0]*a[1]*...a[8];  //  product of all numbers in a, other than a[9];
....
```

Problem: How can we get array `b` populated **without using division operator `/`**? And with a `O(n)` algorithm?

I tried quite a few methods, but still in vain. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you allowed to use exponentiation?

Comment: I think no, the reviewer may reject using this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Firstly, calculate all left and right products:

```
left[i] = a[0]*a[1]*...*a[i]
right[i] = a[i]*a[i+1]*...*a[n-1]
```

Note that `left[i] == left[i-1] * a[i]`, so the `left` array can be computed in linear time. Simlarly, the `right` array can be computed in linear time.

From `left` and `right`, the array `b` can be computed in linear time by `b[i] = left[i-1] * right[i+1]` with special cases for `i == 0` and `i == n`.

Comment: This is really clever!  However, it uses O(n) space, which might be an issue.

Comment: I don't get it. Calculating `left[i]` and `right[i]` is O(n). Calculating `left[0]` to `left[n-1]` and `right[0]` to `right[n-1]` is therefore O(n²). Why do you think it should be O(n)?

Comment: @Oswald - Firstly, calculate all left[i].  Secondly, calculate all rigth[i].

Comment: @Oswald- You can compute left[i+1] from left[i] in O(1) by multiplying left[i] by a[i]

Answer (score 1):

According to Egor Skriptunoff idea, I wrote this code:It is easier to understand:

```
        float l[n];
        float r[n];
        left[0] = 1;
        right[n-1] = 1;
        for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
        {
            l[i] = l[i-1]*a[i-1];
        }
        for (int i=n-2; i>=0; i--)
        {
            r[i] = r[i+1]*a[i+1];
        }
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            b[i] = l[i]*r[i];
        }
```